# What is the difference between the 23 bi-affine and the 39 fully quadratic equations of the rijndael sbox?

Tags: aes, finite-field, rijndael, algebraic-attack

In [Cryptanalysis of Block Ciphers with Overdefined Systems of Equations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/044.pdf) Nicolas Courtois and Josef Pieprzyk define 23 so called **bi-affine** equations (in Appendix A of the paper) between the input x and the output z of the rijndael sbox.

Then they say in A.1 that it is possible to get "not only" 23 bi-affine but 39 **fully quadratic** equations.
And they further describe that the additional 16 equations come from a) $x^4y = x^3$ and b) $y^4x = y^3$.
($y = x^{-1}$ is the result of the inversion in the sbox)

I assume they produce these 16 equations in the very same way how they generated the 23 bi-affine equations (which is described [here](https://scialert.net/fulltext/amp.php?doi=itj.2014.2482.2488) providing more details):

1. They transform/rearrange the equations a) and b) to have 0 on one side.
2. Then they "split" each equation a) and b) in 8 equations for each coefficient, so we have 16 equations in total for both a) and b).
3. Then they substitute all the $y_i$ using the affine transformation of the sbox: 
   $$
   z = M\cdot y + \textrm{63}_{16} \\
   y = M^{-1}\cdot z + M^{-1} \cdot \textrm{63}_{16} \\
     = M^{-1}\cdot z + \textrm{05}_{16} \\
   $$
   which resolves to:
   $$\begin{cases}
   y_7 = z_{1} + z_{4} + z_{6} \\
   y_6 = z_{0} + z_{3} + z_{5} \\
   y_5 = z_{2} + z_{4} + z_{7} \\
   y_4 = z_{1} + z_{3} + z_{6} \\
   y_3 = z_{0} + z_{2} + z_{5} \\
   y_2 = z_{1} + z_{4} + z_{7} + 1 \\
   y_1 = z_{0} + z_{3} + z_{6} \\
   y_0 = z_{2} + z_{5} + z_{7} + 1 \\
   \end{cases}
   $$

I hope these steps are correct, but this way I get to the same 23 bi-affine equations as listed in the papers [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/044.pdf) and [2](https://scialert.net/fulltext/amp.php?doi=itj.2014.2482.2488).

If I do this with a) and b) I get the following result (only one equation out of 16 as example):
$$
0 = x_{1}^{4} z_{0} + x_{6}^{4} z_{0} + x_{0}^{4} z_{1} + x_{1}^{4} z_{1} + x_{2}^{4} z_{1} + x_{7}^{4} z_{1} + x_{1}^{4} z_{2} + x_{2}^{4} z_{2} + x_{4}^{4} z_{2} + x_{6}^{4} z_{2} + x_{6}^{4} z_{3} + x_{7}^{4} z_{3} + x_{0}^{4} z_{4} + x_{1}^{4} z_{4} + x_{3}^{4} z_{4} + x_{4}^{4} z_{4} + x_{5}^{4} z_{4} + x_{7}^{4} z_{4} + x_{1}^{4} z_{5} + x_{3}^{4} z_{5} + x_{4}^{4} z_{5} + x_{5}^{4} z_{5} + x_{0}^{4} z_{6} + x_{1}^{4} z_{6} + x_{2}^{4} z_{6} + x_{3}^{4} z_{6} + x_{4}^{4} z_{6} + x_{6}^{4} z_{6} + x_{3}^{4} z_{7} + x_{5}^{4} z_{7} + x_{6}^{4} z_{7} + x_{5}^{4} + x_{7}^{4} + x_{2}^{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{3}^{2} + x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + x_{4}^{3} + x_{1}^{2} x_{5} + x_{3}^{2} x_{5} + x_{1} x_{5}^{2} + x_{2} x_{5}^{2} + x_{4} x_{5}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} x_{6} + x_{4}^{2} x_{6} + x_{0} x_{6}^{2} + x_{2} x_{6}^{2} + x_{5} x_{6}^{2} + x_{0}^{2} x_{7} + x_{2}^{2} x_{7} + x_{5}^{2} x_{7} + x_{6}^{2} x_{7} + x_{0} x_{7}^{2} + x_{3} x_{7}^{2} + x_{5} x_{7}^{2} + x_{6} x_{7}^{2}\\
$$

I would assume that every exponent $\neq 0$ of any $x_i$ and $z_i$ can be ignored because those variables representent coefficients in $GF(2)$ and can be either $0$ or $1$. *

So when I ignore the exponents this looks very similar to the bi-affine equations (a sum of combinations of $x_i$ and $y_i$, sometimes with terms of only $x_i$ or $y_i$ - the only thing which is new is that there are terms of $x_i$ and $x_j$ multiplied together) and I would like to understand the difference!

**So how are these equations "fully quadratic" and what does it mean exactly? What is the difference to the bi-affine equations besides the number of the equations?**

---

*: This was also necessary in the process of generating the 23 bi-affine equations, where the equation $x^{128} = y^{128} x$ was used. This led to $x_i^{128}$ in the result which to my understanding can also be shortened to $x_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at appendix A of the [eprint](https://ia.cr/2002/044) I'd say that the authors call a polynomial of *algebraic* degree at most $2$ bi-affine, if it contains some terms of algebraic degree $1$, and fully quadratic, if there are no such terms.

(Working over fields of characteristic $2$ the map $x\mapsto x^2$ is linear over the field with two elements and of *algebraic* degree $1$.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me. But when I calculate all the 16 "fully quadratic" equations in GF(2) like mentioned above, I also find a constant term in the very last equation - so it still confuses me.